# AVFoundation: Take High Quality Still Image in Video-Session

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiimage, avfoundation

I am anlysing live-images in a Capture-Session of Type AVMediaTypeVideo. How can I capture a high-quality-still image (not the low-resolution sample buffer), at certain events=

```
var videoCaptureDevice: AVCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
var device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?    
var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
let cameraOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()


//called in view did load
private func setupCamera() {

    let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)        
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480
    if self.captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
        self.captureSession.addInput(input)
    }
    self.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)


    let videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    if self.captureSession.canAddOutput(videoDataOutput){
        self.captureSession.addOutput(videoDataOutput)
        videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
    }

}

func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

 // sampleBuffer is analysed
 // if result is positive, I would like to take a high quality picture

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little snippet that I use in my apps. I hope this will be helpful

```
private func takePhoto() -> Void
{
    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) 
    {
        videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait

        stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: { (sampleBuffer, error) in
            guard let buffer = sampleBuffer else
            {
                return
            }

            let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(buffer)
            let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: imageData as! CFData)
            let cgImageRef = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, 
                decode: nil, 
                shouldInterpolate: true, 
                intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)

            // The image taked
            let image: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)

            // Detenemos la captura de imagenes
            self.captureSession!.stopRunning()
        })
    }
}
```

If you don't set the sessionPreset property of your **captureSession** variable, by default his values is `AVCapture​Session​Preset​High`. The only preset that is higher than this is `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto`

Comment: thanks for the answer! I called your method when the conditions are met, and also set the AVCapture-Session-Preset to Photo in your method (because I need the photo in High Resolution, but the preview in low resolution). However, the image is very dark. Do you know why I can do to make it get enough light?

Comment: @pascal if the image is dark then you didn't allow the session enough time after changing its parameters to get its auto-exposure correct. Change the preset sooner, or adjust other parameters manually